# Why do I get different results from the form post method "GET" vs. the "POST" method in the following?

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, post, get

I have the following HTML/ASP.NET code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ny test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <form action="Default.aspx" runat="server" method="post">

    Name: <input type="text" id="navn" runat="server"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit!" runat="server" />
    <input type="reset" />
    <br />

    <%if (Request.Form["submit"] != null)
      {
          Response.Write("<br/>");
          Response.Write("Submit button pushed");
      }
      if (Request.Form["navn"] != null && Request.Form["navn"] != "")
      {
          Response.Write("<br/>");
          Response.Write("Name OK");
      } 
    %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When using the "POST" form post method I get the following output:

**Submit button pushed 
Name OK**

When using the "GET" form post method **NOTHING** is printed out?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Request.Form` contains information that is sent using `POST`. When you use `GET` the information will be in the `Request.QueryString` collection. In your case this means that `Request.Form["submit"]` is `null`.

If you want to support both then you would be able to use the `Request.Item` collection which includes values from:

- `Request.Cookies`
- `Request.Form`
- `Request.QueryString`
- `Request.ServerVariables`

However, doing this you may get some unexpected results if you use a parameter name that is used in one of the other collections.

Answer (score 1):

To handle both `POST` and `GET` with your code you can just remove the `.Form`, i.e. replace `Request.Form["navn"]` with `Request["navn"]`.

Comment: Thank you! That's a very nice replacement!